# What do you normally do with DB transaction logs?

Tags: database, transactions, data-warehouse

I’m just curious, what do you normally do with transaction logs? I can't find exactly the straightforward explanation for the question. Except for fault tolerance, do you do something like DB restoration? For example, I have a PostgreSQL on top of kubernetes cluster, and I have a Redshift Cluster. If I attach Debezium connector to the PostgreSQL, I can send the transaction log to S3, and make exactly the same table in Redshift Cluster, as the table in PostgreSQL(on top of kubernetes). I’m a junior data engineer, and I’m really curious whether this kind of approach is normal. Thanks much in advance! I'm trying to build a data warehouse and hope someone can answer the question for me.

Comment: Have you used CTRL Z and CTRL Y in MS word ? They are UNDO and REDO feature. You don't need them generally unless something went wrong.

Comment: @GaneshChandrasekaran No, I haven't.

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL terminology for transaction logs is WAL segments or WAL files. DBA must take care to backup them: they are needed to restore databases.

See detail in https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/continuous-archiving.html.